# How to appending 1 value to array A to match the dimensions of array B?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

The program I have here is simulating the velocity of a falling object.
The velocity is calculated by subtracting the y position from time_1 and time_2.

The problem that I have is that the dimensions of array v and array t don't match. Instead of shortening array t I would like to add 0 at the beginning of the v array. So that the graph will show v = 0 at t= 0. Yes, I know it is a small interval and that it does not really matter. But I want to know it for educational purpose.

I'm wondering if i can write the line `v = (y[1:] - y[:-1])/0.1` in a from where i keep the dimension.

The ideal thing that would happen is that the array y will be substracted with an array `y[:-1]` and that this subtraction will happen at the end of the y array so the result will be an array of dimension 101 with a 0 as start value.

I would like to know your thoughts about this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = linspace(0,10,101)
g = 9.80665
y = 0.5*g*t*t

v = (y[1:] - y[:-1])/0.1

plt.plot(t,v)
plt.show()
```

is there a function where i can add a certain value to the beginning of an array? np.append will add it to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could just pre-define the length of the result at the beginning and then fill up the values:

```py
import numpy as np

dt = .1
g = 9.80665
t_end = 10

t = np.arange(0,t_end+dt,dt)
y = 0.5*g*t*t

v = np.zeros(t.shape[0])

v[1:] = (y[1:] - y[:-1])/dt
```

if you simply looking for the append at index function it would be this one:

```py
np.insert([1,2,3,4,5,6], 2, 100)
>> array([  1,   2, 100,   3,   4,   5,   6])
```

Comment: do you know if there is also some append function where you can tell on what index it should append something?

Comment: numpy.insert could be what you are looking for

Comment: I would like to add that initializing an array and fill it will have many advantages. One would be that the location in the memory is fixed and therefore its more efficient and faster when you recalculate stuff.

Comment: i have another question related to this. if i have a time array `t = np.arange(6)` and i have another `array u`. if i want to make `u=3 when  2>= t >= 4 ` and everything else should be ones. I try to use something like this:

 `t = np.arange(6)  and  a = np.ones(6)*3.0*t[2 => t >= 4]`
but this does not work. How can i make this line work?

Answer (score 1):

another possible solution to this would be to use [np.append](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) but inverse your order :

```
import numpy as np

v = np.random.rand(10)
value = 42 # value to append at the beginning of v

value_arr = np.array([value]) # dimensions should be adjust for multidimensional array
v = np.append(arr = value_arr, values = v, axis=0)
```

and the possible variants following the same idea, using [np.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) or [np.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) ...

regarding your second question in comments, one solution may be :

```
t = np.arange(6)

condlist = [t <= 2, t >= 4]
choicelist = [1, 1]
t = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=t)
```